# How to link API requests with request parameters to graphql server query running on another PORT

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, api-gateway, express-gateway

I have an API-Gateway running on some port.
There is an API end point: `fetch/products/`.
Request coming from this API end point with some request parameters needs to be sent to graphql server.
How to dynamically send those JSON request parameters to graphql?

Server1.js

```
const typeDefs = `
  type Query {getproducts(p1: String!,p2: String!,p3: String!,p4: String!,p5:String!
   }
`}

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getproducts: async (_, {p1,p2,p3,p4,p5}) => {
         
      const response = await fetch(`http://service1.com/fetch/products/?p1=${p1}&p2=${p2}&p3=${p3}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      const response2 = await fetch(`http://service2.com/fetch/items/?p1=${p1}&p4=${p4}&p5=${p5}`);
      const data = await response2.json();
     return response1+response2;
}}};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.listen({ port: 1000});
```

api-gateway server file

Request from API-Gateway is made from different port:

```
/fetch/products/?p1=value1&p2=value2&p3=value3&p4=value4&p5=value5&p6=value6
```

#How to send this request to graphql server in this form:

```
http://localhost:1000/graphql/?query={getproducts(p1:"p1",p2:"p2",p3:"p3",p4:"p4",p5:"p5")}
```

When I created object from API-request and stringyfy it then i get keys also in string.

```
 http://localhost:1000/graphql/?query={getproducts("p1":"p1","p2":"p2","p3":"p3","p4":"p4","p5":"p5")}
```

How to handle this? Or some other way to handle request coming from API-Gateway to graphql server with request parameter.

Comment: Why isn’t the data in the message body? If you are using express gateway, can you post the relevant parts of gateway.config.yml?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod , I am using  proxy-policy in express-gateway where I get the request with parameters in JSON format as mentioned above in the body . Now I am proxying it to Graphql server , In Graphql I am fetching the values from proxy-policy in express gateway and getting data from 2 services using those parameters as mentioned above and sending back combined response to proxy-policy in express-gateway.

Comment: What error are getting from graphql?

Comment: I am getting error in graphql that keys cant be string as I am calling graphql with this : http://localhost:1000/graphql/?query={getproducts("p1":"p1","p2":"p2","p3":"p3","p4":"p4","p5":"p5")}

Comment: That is correctly-formed JSON; if graphql is rejecting it, it is not really looking for strict JSON.